# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code M1

Tags: ios, swift, runtime-error, swift5, xcode13

I am using M1 and I got an error when I tried to run my project on simulator.
After some research I added **armv7s armv7 i386 x86_64 arm64** in **Excluded Architectures** and now I got another error saying: **Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code**

[image]

[image]

Comment: There usually is an error message accompanied to PhaseScriptExecution in red letters, could you please share that?

Comment: @JavierHeisecke, I added the photo of the error)

Comment: Did you solve this?